# Degenerate modes in cylindrical wavguide

Tags: waveguide

The $H_z$ field (TE mode)  in the case of the cylindrical weveguide is given by: 
$H_z(\rho, \varphi, z) = H_0 J_m (k_t\rho)e^{i k_z z} e^{\pm i m \varphi} $, where the part that gives the azimuthal modal dependence is given by: $e^{\pm i m \phi} $ and corresponds to the two degenerate modes that exist in this waveguide due to symmetry.

These degenerate modes can be separately represented like:

$$ H_z(\rho, \varphi, z) = H_0 J_m (k_t\rho)e^{i k_z z}  \cos(m \varphi)$$

and

$$ H_z(\rho, \varphi, z) = H_0 J_m (k_t\rho)e^{i k_z z}  \sin(m \varphi) \;.$$

However, I don't understand how the compact notation $e^{\pm i m \varphi} $  is equivalent to the two separate cases: $\cos(m \varphi)$ and $ \sin(m\varphi)\,.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean $\cos(m\phi)$ and $\sin(m\phi)$ in the last sentence? Due to Euler's formula 
$$e^{\pm i m \phi}=\cos(m\phi)\pm i \sin(m\phi)$$
you can represent the two degenerate modes written in exponential form in terms of the ones with $\sin$ and $\cos$. You can write 
$$H_z^{\pm}(\rho, \phi, z) = H_0 J_m (k_t\rho)e^{i k_z z} e^{\pm i m \phi} =$$

$$H_0 J_m (k_t\rho)e^{i k_z z} (\cos(m\phi)\pm i \sin(m\phi)) = H_z^{c}(\rho, \phi, z)\pm i H_z^{s}(\rho, \phi, z)$$

and vice-versa, so that the last two modes are just simple complex linear combinations of the first two that you wrote.

Comment: In general I am familiar with the Euler's formula but the whole problem started from another form of the expression:  
$ H_z = (A\cos(m\phi) + B\sin(m\phi))J_m(k_c \rho) e^{i k_z z}$, where each of the degenerate modes is given by its own constant which  physically corresponds to how the feeding couples the energy. I understand now that I wrongly assumed A and B are real. If they are complex, the compact notation makes immediate sense.

Answer (score 1):

The modes with sine and cosine are linear combinations of the modes with $\exp(+im\phi)$ and $\exp(-im\phi)$, so the word "equivalent" is too strong.